# why devops service prinicple does not have synapse administrator role when created synapse workspace using bicep code

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-synapse

I have created Azure synapse workspace using bicep code:

```
  resource synapse 'Microsoft.Synapse/workspaces@2021-06-01' = {
  name: synapseName
  location: location
  tags: tags
  identity: {
    type: 'SystemAssigned'
  }
  properties: {
    defaultDataLakeStorage: {
      accountUrl: 'https://${synapseDefaultStorageAccountName}.dfs.${environment().suffixes.storage}'
      filesystem: synapseDefaultStorageAccountFileSystemName
    }
    managedResourceGroupName: synapseName
    managedVirtualNetwork: 'default'
    managedVirtualNetworkSettings: {
      allowedAadTenantIdsForLinking: []
      linkedAccessCheckOnTargetResource: true
      preventDataExfiltration: true
    }
    publicNetworkAccess: 'Disabled'
    purviewConfiguration: empty(XXX) ? {} : {
      purviewResourceId: XXXX
    }
    sqlAdministratorLogin: administratorUsername
    sqlAdministratorLoginPassword: administratorPassword
    virtualNetworkProfile: {
      computeSubnetId: subnetId
    }
  }
}
```

Synapse is being created but and in the access control section I see synapse itself as Synapse Administrator role. I expected devops Service principal too here.

Need: I need to assign this Synapse Administrator role to certain group within the same pipeline where I am deploying synapse. I dont want to add devops service connection spn manually.

after the deployment when deployment goes to powershell step, It throws error:

```
  - task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
    name: Ingest_Application_Infrastructure_deployment
    displayName: Ingest Application Infrastructure deployment
    continueOnError: false
    inputs:
      deploymentScope: "Subscription"
      azureResourceManagerConnection: ${{ parameters.AZURE_RESOURCE_MANAGER_CONNECTION_NAME }}
      subscriptionId: $(AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID)
      location: ${{ parameters.AZURE_LOCATION }}
      templateLocation: "Linked artifact"
      csmFile: "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/infra/main.bicep"
      csmParametersFile: "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/${{ parameters.PARAMETER_FILE_PATH }}"
      deploymentMode: "Incremental"
      deploymentOutputs: ingestDeploymentOutputs
      overrideParameters: >
        -environment "${{ parameters.ENVIRONMENT }}"

  ##Add Synapse Administrator Role to Synapse
  - task: AzureCLI@2
    displayName: "Add Synapse Administrator Role"
    enabled: true
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.AZURE_RESOURCE_MANAGER_CONNECTION_NAME }}
      scriptType: "pscore"
      scriptLocation: "scriptPath"
      ScriptPath: "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/code/MYSCRIPT.ps1"
      ScriptArguments: >
        -DeploymentOutputs '$(ingestDeploymentOutputs)'
```

Error: ERROR: (Unauthorized) The principal 'XXXXXXXXXX' does not have the required Synapse RBAC permission to perform this action. Required permission: Action: Microsoft.Synapse/workspaces/read, Scope: workspaces/MYSYNAPSEWORKSPACENAME/*.
Code: Unauthorized

what could wrong here? Thanks in advance

Comment: As stated in error, Have you assigned the RBAC role to the service principal? Required permission: 
Action: Microsoft.Synapse/workspaces/read,
Scope: workspaces/MYSYNAPSEWORKSPACENAME/*.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Something has clearly changed in the Synapse resource provider, as previously the workspace creator would automatically be granted a Synapse Administrator role. You can use the `Microsoft.Synapse workspaces/administrators` resource to grant the DevOps service principal both the workspace AD admin role (shown in Portal under the Synapse resource's Azure Active Directory blade) and the Synapse Administrator role.

In my case I wanted to have the Synapse Administrator role for both the DevOps service principal and an AD group. As there can only be one workspace AD admin, I needed to add an extra step to for adding the Synapse Administrator role for the AD group. So first I granted the DevOps SP the workspace AD admin role in the bicep deployment. Then I added an Azure CLI task to my deployment to add the Synapse Administrator role to the AD group (`az synapse role assignment create`).